# Best practices to write utility classes in google-guice?

Tags: java, guice

I have started to get my feet wet with guice so please pardon my ignorance. Consider the following util class

```
public class UtilClass {
   public Image resizedImageDimensions(int Originalwidth,int Originalheight,int ResizedWidth,int ResizedHeight) {
    // Return an image object which is resized based on the parameters provided
   }
   // More helper methods below....
}
```

`UtilClass` does not need to implement any interface. This `UtilClass` will be used in other classes to get resized Image based on the original image dimensions (class also includes other utility methods). 

Should I just inject the instance of this class like `bind(UtilClass.class);` or does it make sense to create an interface and bind that class to that interface (even though the interface is not needed) ? 

Also, if there is a better way of adding utility classes in guice then please share as well.

P.S: I thought about making methods in the class static. But, I am afraid it might be a pain to unit test if this function was static.

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject Util Class with Google Guice vs static Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370683/inject-util-class-with-google-guice-vs-static-methods)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with static methods for pure functions and it shouldn't hurt your testing. If you don't want to make the method static you don't need to have an interface. You could just `bind(UtilClass.class)` and `@Inject` it where required.

Comment: @condit thanks for the reply. I read http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/LinkedBindings and couldn't find a bind example without an interface. That's why the doubt whether its ok to use it or not.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings. Also, if your utility class doesn't have a constructor you shouldn't even need to `bind` it.

Comment: @condit. Sweet ! That is really helpful. Note to self:Read entire documentation first.

Comment: added as an answer if you want to close it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with static methods for [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and it shouldn't hurt your testing. If you don't want to make the method static you don't need to have an interface.
Have a look at the documentation on [untargetted bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings). If your utility class doesn't have a constructor you shouldn't even need to bind it.